# Powershell Profile is not available over ssh

Tags: windows-10, ssh, powershell, profile

I have installed openssh on my windows 10 desktop through the apps and features menu. I can ssh to the machine and see my files as my regular user.

I can access my files, but $PROFILE results in "is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Commands such as nap and vim that I have added to my profile also are not recognized.

Comment: $profile is an env variable only on your machine that you are using PowerShell from. You cannot use local variables in a remote session without properly scoping them. This is well documented in the PowerShell help files covering variables, and remoting. Similar concerns/limitations are the same when you are trying to run cmdline or other tools on your location machine in a remote session. The Windows versions of these tools are not the same binary / exe thing as those on *nix. When you are in a remote session, unless it's implicit, you are on the remote host, not your system, thus, your issues

Comment: after reading a bit, it looks I need to use [powershell remote](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/ssh-remoting-in-powershell-core?view=powershell-6)